# Designing specific feature in ddd

Tags: domain-driven-design

A string parser that coresponds to a specific domain should be considered as a utility or a domain/value object?

Example: User submits a search request for a financial instrument. E.g "OMX KR Equity". In order to submit such string to a provider it has to be parsed and mapped to its exact values (instrument name, marketplace code, instrument type). Search request file structure depends on instrument type, so after the string gets parsed an instrument type has to be checked against existing types in the database. If it does not exist the search request can not be submitted and the user must receive response accordingly.

(It is a bit different search than you might expect. User submits a search request. Application submits search request to external provider via FTP by generating a request file. After some time request gets fulfilled and it is being fetched back from the FTP and saved to the database. So there is no immediate response for the search request.)

I cant find a proper place to put this logic in. Normally it could be a value object within the SearchRequest entity, but the need to validate against the database raises an issue.

Also I am trying to avoid introducing static solutions because I suspect it makes testing more difficult. Especially if it is considered domain logic, I dont think it should belong to a static method as a utility, helper or etc.

What would be the correct ways of solving this issue according to ddd?

Comment: A search normally doesn't modify the domain model, so why do you need to validate the instrument type?  "Validate" is a strange way to spell "do something else if this instrument isn't supported".

Comment: Updated the question with more information

Comment: Is the search query format a constraint of all search providers (given there would be more) or is it specific to the current provider? I'd probably have an interface such as `ISearchProvider { List<SearchQueryError> validateQuery(String searchQuery), ... }` and implement that in the infrastructure. `ISearchProvider` and `SearchQueryError` could be defined in the domain or the application service layer (not sure where is best).

Answer (score 1):

> A string parser that coresponds to a specific domain should be
>   considered as a utility or a domain/value object?

It should be a `Value object` that would validate the format in the constructor (for example using regular expressions : `[A-Z]{3}\s[A-Z]{2}\s[a-zA-Z]{1,}`) and that will have only three getters for the three parts of this string : `getName():string`, `getType():string`, `getCode():string`. Lets name this class:  `InstrumentQuery`. It has *[only one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)* responsability: validate+parse the string.

> Search request file structure depends on instrument type, so after the
>   string gets parsed an instrument type has to be checked against
>   existing types in the database.

The "checking against existing types in the database" is done in the `Application service` that receive the search command, before dispatching the command to the `SearchRequest aggregate`. Although in most of the existing domains in the wide world a search is a [query method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) of some kind, in your domain a `SearchRequest` is an `Aggregate`. This aggregate has a `submitQuery(InstrumentQuery instrumentQuery)` [command method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Depending on your design, an `InstrumentType` is an `Entity` (so it has an `ID`) or a `Value object`. If it is a `Entity` then the `submitQuery` may receive its `ID`; it depends on the internal usage. In any case, its existence is checked before the command reaches the `SearchRequestAggregate` by trying to load it from the `Repository`.

> Especially if it is considered domain logic, I dont think it should
>   belong to a static method as a utility, helper or etc.

As you can see, you have two different validations:

1. The format of the `SearchRequest`: pure domain logic, stays inside `ValueObject`, inside domain code layer.
2. The existence of a `InstrumentType`: application layer logic, checked by trying to load it from a repository.

Comment: I like the general idea, but I have a question regarding SearchQuery value object. I have noticed that exceptions are used as a way to prevent from creating a false state domain object (e.g checking for nulls) specifically in the constructor. But I have never seen these exceptions being catched. And it would not look like a good approach if you had to do so. Would it be correct to say that these kind of exceptions are a part of public api for a developer? I guess the alternative would be to introduce a property IsValid in the value object and check it before going any further.

Comment: @DasBoot I like very much throwing Exceptions in order to abandon the `happy path` in case of invalid data as they make the `happy path` more clear. And yes, the public API should contain/document these exceptions as first class citizens. The alternative, an `isValid` method, is not optimal because it creates a temporal coupling between the usage/`getters` and `isValid`: one **must remeber** to call isValid before using the object.

Comment: Does it mean that you would normally wrap your object instantiations with a try catch clause or you just catch specific domain exceptions at the top most layer? Personally I would not use exceptions for business validation cases. Appreciate your answers.